# Typescript Promise curry function when using bind

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I have this snippet of code that is using a Server typing from node:net.

I'm trying to set the correct typing for the curry function.

```js
const originalClose = server.close.bind(server) as Server['close']; // node:net Server typing
server.close = () => new Promise((resolveClose) => {
    originalClose(resolveClose);
});
```

At the moment, I get this typescript error:

```
Type 'Promise<unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'Server': listen, close, address, getConnections, and 20 more.ts(2740)
```

I've tried using `Promise<Server>` as well as `Promise<Server['close']>` but I actually realized I'm wrapping the resolve(?) case within the bounded `originalClose` const.

My question is how can I get the correct typing here: `server.close = () /** :WhatTypingHere */=> ...`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's the type of value `originalClose` is going to reolve using `resolveClose`. For e.g, if it's `resolveClose(true)` then type becomes `Promise<boolean>`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Are you trying to promisify the close callback?

Comment: @Chase yes that's exactly what i'm doing

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `close` function **must** return the value it was bound with, which, in this case is possibly of type `Server`. So the `close` function should be a function that returns a value of type `Server`. But your code returns a promise, not a `Server`.

Approach the problem the other way around, usually people promisify by *wrapping* the callback in a promise, not by overriding the callback itself.

```
function promisifiedServerClose(s: Server) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s.close(err => {
            if (!err) {
                resolve(s);
            } else {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This is a very common pattern that you can *almost always* use to promisify things.

It will be separate from the `.close` function since this is a *promisified* version and `.close` is a callback version. Overriding a well known function to make it do something completely different is not only difficult but also a very bad and misleading practice, so use a separate function instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I need to explore more about how `.close` is called. I assume it happens when i do a ctrl+c, so it may be more convenient for me to override the original but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: @joshuar500 Why do you need to promisify something that you won't ever call yourself, but rather the runtime will?

Comment: i am following a tutorial, but I want to use typescript with it as well: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-i-structure-express-apps